# Why Brendan roll the cigaratte with his foot?

Tags: plot-explanation, brick

In *Brick (2005)*, Emily slips a note in Brendans locker telling him
to go to a specific phone booth.

She calls the phone booth, and they talk for a little. She says shes in trouble, but uses words Brendan doesn't know to describe the problem (Poor Frisco, Pin, brick, Tug).

A black car drives by and Emily screams. The passenger in the car drops a 
cigarette & Brendan rolls the cigaratte with his foot & a blue arrow mark is found on it.

Why did he roll it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely to see which brand of cigarette it is. The brand is often found near the filter; and as you can see in the image you linked, the cigarette has not yet burned all the way up to the filter.

Especially in older whodunnit stories, criminals can be identified by the brand of cigarettes that they smoke. Even if it's not definitive proof, it can help you in finding the right suspect.

An example of Camel cigarettes:

[image: Example]